# reading bytes literally in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am reading three bytes from a file in python 
the bytes in the hex format 
exact byte values are \x00 \x07 \x71

but when I read these bytes using fp.read method python converts the last byte to q

Is there any way to avoid the conversion when python reads the bytes to ASCII and literally read the byte value

Comment: Do you read the file in byte-mode, i.e. `open("filename", "rb")`? In that case Python doesn't really "convert" anything, it just chooses to display `0x71` as "q", but that is identical. Note for example that `b"q"[0] == 113`.

Comment: But the result from your `fp.read` is a `bytes` object, isn't it? `71` is the ASCII hex value for `q` which is why it is displayed as `q`. It is not converting it to `q`, it ***is*** `q`. If you re-write your data to a new file, it will write `\x71`. If `a = b"\x00\x07\x71"`, then `print(a[2])` will print `113`, which is the decimal value for hex 71.

Comment: Can you post the code you are having issues for us to try to help?

Comment: @SyntaxVoid thanks for the reply , the issue is that I want to convert it to it's integer value , 000771 is 1905 but when i try to convert the hexstring 0007q to int using int(0007q, 16) I get an error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16

Comment: @SyntaxVoid int('000771', 16) gives 1905

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, it sounds like you need to convert an arbitrary number of bytes to a single integer. So `\x00\x07\x71` should be treated as one binary number. If you wanted to write your own function (which isn't too hard), you can iterate through each byte and bit-shift it appropriately dependent on its position.

For your example of `a = b"\x00\x07\x71"`, this expands to the binary number `a_b = 0b00000000_00000111_01110001`. We start with the right-most byte. This doesn't need to be bitshifted at all - we add it to the result. We move on to the 2nd byte (`\x07`). This needs to be leftshifted 1 byte and then added to the result. Finally, the leftmost byte needs to be leftshifted 2 bytes and then added to the result. So our *by-hand* calculation yields (113 + 7*2^8 + 0*2^16 = 113 + 1792 + 0 = 1905)

```py
def b_concat(bs):
  """
  Performs binary concatenation of an arbitrary number of 8-bit values.
  b_concat stands for binary-concatenation.

  Input:
    bs: bytes - A bytes string to convert to a single integer

  Returns: The concatenated result as an integer. See examples below
  """
  result = 0
  n = len(bs)
  for i in range(n):
    result += (bs[n - i - 1] << (8*i)) # or you can use bs[::-1][i]
  return result

tests = [b"\x00", b"\x01", b"\x02", b"\x00\x01", b"\x14\xa2", b"\x00\x07\x71"]
for test in tests:
  print(f"{test} --> {b_concat(test)}")
```

or a 1-liner, if you prefer

```py
def b_concat(bs):
    return sum([bs[::-1][i] << (8*i) for i in range(len(bs))])
```

In either case, the output is

```
b'\x00' --> 0
b'\x01' --> 1
b'\x02' --> 2
b'\x00\x01' --> 1
b'\x14\xa2' --> 5282
b'\x00\x07q' --> 1905
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution I use the binascii.b2a_hex to convert binary values to their hexadecimal representation and the use int(converted_val, 16) to get integer value